# Get approximate square root

Tags: java, algorithm, math, sqrt, math.sqrt

I'm implementing [Babylonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_mathematics) method to approximate the square root of number `n` using following formula :

```
nextGuess = (lastGuess + n / lastGuess) / 2;
```

So when `nextGuess` and `lasGuess` are almost identical, `nextGuess` is the approximated square root.

What am doing is checking if `nextGuess` and `lastGuess` is less than very small number such as `0.0001` then i can claim that `nextGuess` is the approximated square root of `n`. if not `nextGuess` become `lastGuess`.

So how i can implement that in the right way?

My current code:

```
public static void getApproximatedSquare(long n){
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
    decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);

    double lastGuess = 1, nextGuess;

    nextGuess = (lastGuess + n / lastGuess) / 2;
    Double init =  0.0001;
    System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(init));
    if (Double.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(nextGuess)) <= init)
        //todo

}
```

Comment: What answer would you expect for `getApproximatedSquare(4611685984067649600L)`?

Comment: @JamesKPolk that's why i'm using `DecimalFormat` the result would be `2147483640` and that's approximation value for your number.

Answer (score 4):

Current draft of implementation has a few flaws:

- I doubt you really need `Double.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(...))`, it just removes some precision from the result
- Your convergence condition is not `nextGuess < init` but `difference_between_nextGuess_and_lastGuess < init`
- You have to repeat the approximation until convergence, so you can't use just a `if`. You need a `for` or `while` or (as in my solution) `do... while`
- This should work (at each step, it prints last and next guesses)

  ```
  public static double getApproximatedSquare(long n) {
      DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
      decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);

      double lastGuess, nextGuess = 1;
      double init = 0.0001;
      do {
          lastGuess = nextGuess;
          nextGuess = (lastGuess + (double) n / lastGuess) / 2;
          System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(lastGuess)+" ---> "+decimalFormat.format(nextGuess));
      } while (Math.abs(lastGuess - nextGuess) >= init);
      return nextGuess;
  }
  ```

Comment: it would be a perfect one if the `nextGuess` square is really equal to `n`, how i can make it exactly the same ?

Answer (score 1):

Using an absolute tolerance is always a bad idea because it doesn't take into account the order of magnitude of the argument. A relative error is better.

But in the case of the square root, I recommend a much better approach: make sure that your initial approximation is within a factor √2 of the exact root. This is obtained by halving the exponent of 2 in the floating-point representation of the argument. (If you can't access this exponent, you can obtain it by successive divisions or multiplications until to reach the interval [1, 2).)

Example: for 27, you have 16 ≤ 27 < 32. Then 1 ≤ √27 / 4 < √2, and you can start the iterations from 4.

Then perform **four iterations** of the Babylonian formula. No less, no more.

In the example, after four iterations, you obtain 5.19615242271, which is exact.

---

If you have the feeling that the successive halving or doubling process is slow and believe that Newton is faster, consider that (x + n / x) / 2 > x / 2, so that Newton actually converges slower than halvings and involves more arithmetic
 !

Comment: Because the argument is a `long` rather than a double or float, it's a little more complicated.

Comment: @JamesKPolk: the OP is using doubles for intermediate computation, so the input type does not matter. (By the way, the Babylonian method works equally well with pure integer arithmetic and maybe 3 iterations are enough.)

Answer (score 0):

If `nextGuess`'s value is 100% sure to go down and reach a good enough value, can't you just do this?

```
public static void getApproximatedSquare(long n){
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
    decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);

    double lastGuess = n + 1;
    double nextGuess = n;
    double init      = 0.0001;

    while (lastGuess - nextGuess > init)
    {
        lastGuess = nextGuess;
        nextGuess = (lastGuess + n / lastGuess) / 2;
    }

    System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(init));
}
```

Comment: Why should `nextGuess`, the approximation, ever reach `0.0001` for every input number `n`? Did you mean something like `while (|nextguess² - n| > init)`?

Comment: Woops, looks like I made a mistake. Correcting it right now

Answer (score -1):

As `nextGuess` approaches `sqrt(n)` from above, you can use this:

```
double lastGuess = n;
double nextGuess = n;
double epsilon = 1e-4;
while (lastGuess - nextGuess > epsilon) {
    lastGuess = nextGuess;
    nextGuess = (lastGuess + n / lastGuess) / 2;
}
```